# CSS input one-level positioning

Tags: css, sass

I have kind of difficult css positioning for me and need help. The problem is a have a row of div with flex-wrap: wrap. (picture 1)

[image]

Each div have 50% width so we have 2 columns. I need each input of 2 element in row have to be on the the same position. (picture 2)

[image]

You can see that all element on the same label, independent of title's height and error's height. I tried to use align-items: flex-start/end, but it doesn't work cause if you use start you depend on title's height and if you use flex-end then you depend on error's height. In both way moved on the different level. I hope that I explained clear. Can you tell me how I can achieve this behavior?

I tried to use different flex-items properties value, but it didn't work. I would appreciate if you tell me how to place divs like on the picture 2.

I have already asked this question before and got one answer which I thought was correct, but unfortunately it wasn's.
Morgan Freeney give me a solution, but it has one critical problem for me.
If you make error bigger, label become bigger too. How can I fix it? I want them take accordingly to their size.

[image]

Morgan's solution on [codepen](https://codepen.io/morganfeeney/pen/zYaWqLK?editors=1100)

```css
.form {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1rem;
}

.form-group {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto 1fr;
}

label {
  font-weight: bold;
  align-self: end;
}
```

```html
<form class="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="1">Input label</label>
    <input id="1" type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="2">Input label</label>
    <input id="2" type="text">
    <div>Some error, maybe long</div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="3">Input label</label>
    <input id="3" type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="4">Input label</label>
    <input id="4" type="text">
    <div>A really, lreally looooooong error message that wraps onto multiple lines and may never happen in real life</div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="5">Input label that is running onto multiple lines and is the root of the issue</label>
    <input id="5" type="text">
    <div>A really, really looooooong error message that wraps onto multiple lines and may never happen in real life, A really, reeaaaaeally looooooong error message that wraps onto multiple lines and may never happen in real life</div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="6">Input label</label>
    <input id="6" type="text">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: If you change .form-group to have just .form-group {display: flex; flex-direction: column;}, would you get what you wanted? (and remove the self-align) - https://cln.sh/qLnConyYFPcyH5eUe1ar I am not posting as an answer as I am not sure if this is the end goal, because I am not sure what is the reason of having grid inside the grid here.

Comment: The reason why the top and bottom of your form group items are the same height is because .form-group grid-template-rows are set to 1fr auto 1fr. It's aligning because the input box is a fixed height and it's using the 1fr component to fill the parent evenly top and bottom.

Answer (score 0):

try

```css
.form-group {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```